# How to change the position of single label manually using tmap?

Tags: r, tmap

When I add the polygon labels to my maps using tm_text function it sometimes happens that some labels overlap. Is there any way to change the position of single labels manually avoiding they overlap?

Here an example of the problem using data from Tigris package:

```
library(tigris)
library(tmap)

# load county data for Illinois
il_counties <- counties(state = "IL", cb = TRUE)

# map county polygons with labels
tm_shape(il_counties) +
tm_polygons() +
tm_text(text = "NAME", size = 0.8, col = "black", root = TRUE)
```

As can be seen there are many labels partially overlapping. In my case I have just few labels that partially overlap, this is why I thought I could modify their position manually.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code with data using `dput`?

Comment: Hello @Quinten , thanks for your answer. I did it using Tigris package.

Answer (score 1):

An option could be by changing the `size` to some point where you almost see no overlap like this:

```r
library(tigris)
library(tmap)

# load county data for Illinois
il_counties <- counties(state = "IL", cb = TRUE)

# map county polygons with labels
tm_shape(il_counties) +
  tm_polygons() +
  tm_text(text = "NAME", size = 0.4, col = "black", root = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I tried changing the size but in my case it is not a good option as to erase the overlapping issues I should set very small size values, undermining the readability of the labels. Actually, I have a partial overlap problem just with a few labels, this is why I thought to change their position manually. Anyway, I couldn't find a solution with tm_text arguments although it looks so strange to me that one doesn't have the possibility to make any change to the position of labels.